# Cloning JSON not working as expected

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON literal as follows:

```
var json_1 = {
    "name": "Tim",
    "toys": ["ball", "bat", "lego"]
};
```

Now I clone this as follows:

```
var json_2 = json_1;
```

If I remove a toy from `json_1` (using `splice()`)the same seems to be getting removed from `json_2`.
How do I create a copy without them being dependent on each other?

Comment: That's ***not*** a "JSON literal".  It's an "**object** literal".  It has *nothing* to do whatsoever with JSON.

Comment: This is not JSON. This is a javascript object using the object literal syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
var json_2 = json_1
```

you're actually not "cloning" the object you're merely aliasing it. So all operation on json_1 will be mirrored on json_2 and vice versa.
To really clone your object take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/2003420